# Is there a reliable way to reconnect a paired ZAGG - Logitech Bluetooth Keyboard upon power-up?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, ubuntu-18.04, pairing

I have a bluetooth keyboard that I use on a regular basis. It has a Logitech logo, but is manufactured by ZAGG and has model number Y-R0023.

I have paired the keyboard with my Ubuntu desktop and it works great.

Upon powering up my computer and keyboard, I can sometimes reconnect without having to pair again, but other times I have to remove the existing pairing and reconnect before Ubuntu can receive keystrokes.

Extra information: Ubuntu displays a bluetooth symbol as a status when it connects (regardless if it is able to receive keystrokes or not).  This symbol will appear and disappear roughly every 10 seconds until the two devices are able to successfully negotiate a valid connection.

I notice that I have best success when I press 'delete-delete-enter-enter' after powering the ZAGG keyboard up.  (Sometimes, just repeatedly pressing a key every second or so seems to work too.)

I am wondering if the "delete-delete-enter" keystroke combination (or some other that I haven't discovered) is recognized by the Logitech BIOS as a special sequence to help retry a paired re-connection.  I'd be interested in finding out if this trick works for devices other than those made by ZAGG.  Otherwise, it would help just to know if there is a reliable script I can run that calls bluetoothctl to help improve the re-connection. (I want to avoid having to enter a pairing code on subsequent connections).

Comment: The alternative is to press ENTER at the bash command prompt repeatedly.  In response I see messages like `"Bluetooth: hci0: ACL packet for unknown connection handle #"`, where # starts at 1 and increments up to 7 or more every third or fourth time I press Enter.  Typically the connection succeeds before the 20th time I press Enter.

Answer (score 1):

ZAGG sites and Logitech ones don't say anything about this key combination. So I don't think it's recognized as a special sequence, only advice they give is to re-pair the device when it's not working.
In summary I'm sure they would include this troubleshooting option in manual and/or troubleshooting guide if it was present.

Comment: I agree, but I did notice [this post online](https://ulrichard.ch/blog/index.php/2016/12/09/resetting-the-logitech-k810-bluetooth-keyboard/) that suggests that logitech has some special key sequences for some of its devices

Comment: For some yes, but they say about factory resets. This combination from this link is factory reset of keyboard internal memory that contains settings, Y-R0023 don't store this type of information inside, it's mainly used for iPads. "Case has no memory effect" is also said in manual for this keyboard so that means that it can't store data, so factory resets are not a thing. I think connectivity issues are being caused by pairing it with PC and it wasn't meant to be used in that way.

Comment: Your comments are valid, so I have upvoted your reply.  I'd prefer another answer (from you or others) with some hints on how to more reliably reconnect.  I've added a little more detail to my original question to help with that.

Comment: Here is something I found, it's about a speaker auto pairing using bluetoothctl. This might resolve your problem:
[link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53408/automatically-connect-trusted-bluetooth-speaker)

It's for Bluetooth speaker but it should work the same since keyboard is also a bluetooth device that u want to auto-pair.